# How can I customize the behavior of Math.Round in .NET?

Tags: .net, vb.net, math, rounding

I have to use a round method that follows this behavior:

7.00  -> round -> 7
7.50  -> round -> 7
7.51  -> round -> 8

I tried to use Math.Round, but it works a little bit different.

```
Dim val As Decimal = 7.5
Dim a As Decimal = Math.Round(val, 0) ' -> 8
Dim b As Decimal = Math.Round(val, 0, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero) ' -> 8
Dim c As Decimal = Math.Round(val, 0, MidpointRounding.ToEven) ' -> 8
```

How can I implement my rounding logic?

Comment: So you want all variants of X.5 to equal X? The standard for C# is that if the value is X.5 it's rounded towards the nearest even number. So both 7.5 and 8.5 will be rounded to 8.

Comment: By the way, your code is VB, not C#

Comment: why have you marked this question as C# (in both tags and title) but posted VB code?

Comment: Simple answer: The way you want to round is wrong. It doesn't follow any standard convention, and is therefore pretty useless. The .NET Framework gives you the two commonly-accepted forms: `AwayFromZero` (also known as what you learned in school) and `ToEvent` (also known as "Banker's" rounding). Details are in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.midpointrounding.aspx).

Comment: Sorry I messed up code project...I dev on C# and VB...and sometimes it drive me crazy :) However, I know that it isn't the standard behavior but there is a special case in which have to do it.

Answer (score 2):

You could subtract `0.01` from the total and then call `Math.round(..)`.

```
double d = 7.5;
double result = Math.Round(d - 0.01);
```

If the number is negative you will have to do the following to get the same result:

```
double d = -7.5;
if (d < 0)
{
    double tmp = Math.Abs(d) - 0.01;
    double result = -Math.Round(tmp);
}
```

Working example [here](http://www.ideone.com/uETBA).

Note however that this behaviour is probably **not** what you want as noted by several others.

If you read the comments of this answer, @alex zhevzhik also noted that this solution will fail if the input would have more than 2 decimals.

Comment: And what does your solution do when the number is negative?

Comment: What about rounding 7.50000009? You solution will round it to 7.0 meanwhile everything points that the correct answer is 8.0

Comment: @alex zhevzhik: You're right but, the example given by LukePet does not suggest that he will encounter such a number.

Answer (score 1):

[Midpoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.midpointrounding.aspx) couldn't provide appropriate functionality. Take a look at first and third rows in the table in remarks. If you change your val to 6.5, you will get expected behaviour, but not with 7.5.

You should write your own implementation of such rounding.

Javed Akram's implementation is good, but it works completely wrong with negative numbers.
As you didn't provide details of rounding of negative numbers, I suppose standart rounding suits. In addition you should take into account "special" double values:

```
static class Helper
{
    public static double Round(double val)
    {
        if (Double.IsNaN(val) || Double.IsNegativeInfinity(val) || Double.IsPositiveInfinity(val))
        {
            return val;
        }

        var decimalPart = Math.Truncate(val);
        if (val >= 0)
        {
            if (val - decimalPart <= 0.5)
            {
                return Math.Floor(val);
            }
            else
            {
                return Math.Ceiling(val);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return Math.Round(val, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I don't know if there is a Math.Round method that does what you want, but I think you will need to write your own. Because normally, 7.5 would be rounded to 8, unless I forgot everything learned in highschool.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Dim i As Decimal
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim k As Decimal

    i = 7.51
    k = i - Math.Truncate(i)  'decimal part of number

    If (k <= 0.5) Then
        j = Math.Floor(i)
    Else
        j = Math.Ceiling(i)
    End If
```